# Java stacktrace utils library?

Tags: java, stack-trace, analysis

I'm looking for some stacktrace analysis and manipulation library.

It should contain methods like

- `StackTraceElement findFirstSublassOf( Class cls, StackTraceElement[] stacktrace)`
- `StackTraceElement[] stacktrace findCommonRoot( StackTraceElement[] st1, StackTraceElement[] st2 )`
- `StackTraceElement[] stacktrace removeCommon( StackTraceElement[] st1, StackTraceElement[] st2 )`
- `boolean contains( Class cls, StackTraceElement[] stacktrace)`
- various formatting methods
- remove various frameworks' generated proxy methods

etc. Ideally, it could be in a wrapper class `StackTrace` or such.

Didn't find in Commons.